# Какой наиболее правильный MIME для ответа с JSON?

Tags: json, mime

Какое-то время, я отсылал ответ с JSON просто как простой текст: `plain/text`, однако, хотелось бы, наконец, отправлять правильный `Content-Type`-заголовок.

Вот некоторые из предлагаемых "стандартов" для JSON MIME:

```
application/json
application/x-javascript
text/javascript
text/x-javascript
text/x-json
```

Однако, какой из них верный или просто лучший относительно безопасности/поддержки клиентов (браузеры и т. п.)?

<sup>[Перевод вопроса "What is the correct JSON content type?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816)</sup>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для [`JSON`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

> Согласно регистрации [`IANA`](http://www.iana.org/) и [RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt): **`application/json`** в кодировке **`UTF-8`**.

Для [`JSONP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):

> **`application/javascript`** так же в **`UTF-8`**.

---

Когда [создателя JSON Дугласа Крофорда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4,_%D0%94%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81) спросили почему не `text/json`, он ответил что это и не JS-скрипт, но и не текст, поэтому скорее `application/*`, чем `text/*`.